# Is it possible to just get the tags without a class or id with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have several thousands HTML sites and I am trying to filter the text from these sites.

I am doing this with beautiful soup. `get_text()` gives me to much unecessary information from these sites.

Therefore I wrote a loop:

```
l = []
for line in text5:                   
    soup = bs(line, 'html.parser')
    p_text = ' '.join(p.text for p in soup.find_all('p'))  
    k = p_text.replace('\n', '')
    l.append(k)
```

But this loop gives me everything that was in a tag that starts with `<p`.

For example:

I want everything between two plain `<p>` tags.
But I also get the content from someting like this:

`<p class="header-main__label"> bla ba </p>`.

Can I tell BeautifulSoup to just get the plain `<p>` tags?

Comment: `soup.find_all('p', class_=False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `False` for `class` and `id` and it will get tags without `class` and `id`

```
soup.find_all('p', {'class': False, 'id': False})
```

or (word `class_` has `_` because there is keyword `class` in Python)

```
soup.find_all('p', class_=False, id=False)
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '<p class="A">text A</p>  <p>text B</p>  <p id="C">text C</p>'

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

# ----

all_items = soup.find_all('p', {'class': False, 'id': False})

for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)

# ---

all_items = soup.find_all('p', class_=False, id=False)

for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want tags without any attributes then you can filter items using `not item.attrs`

```
for item in all_items:
    if not item.attrs:
        print(item.text)
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '<p class="A">text A</p> <p>text B</p> <p id="C">text C</p> <p data="D">text D</p>'

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_items = soup.find_all('p')

for item in all_items:
    if not item.attrs:
        print(item.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer!