# Need help in Python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a simple code to scrape title, address, contct_person, phone number and website link but my program just scraping title and I don't know how to scrape all other thing because there are no classes and id's for them.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):

    try:
        title = soup.find('a',class_="ListingDetails_Level1_SITELINK",id=False).text
    except:
        title = 'empty'  
    print(title)
    try:
        address = soup.find('div',class_="ListingDetails_Level1_CONTACTINFO",id=False).find_all('span').text
    except:
        address = "address"
    print(address)
    try:
        person_name = soup.find('a',class_="",id=False).find_all('img').text
    except:
        person_name = "empty person"
    print(person_name)
    try:
        phone_no = soup.find('img',class_="",id=False).text
    except:
        phone_no = "empty phone no"
    print(phone_no)
    try:
        website = soup.find('a',class_="",id=False).text
    except:
        website = "empty website"
    print(website)




def main():
    url = "https://secure.kelownachamber.org/Pools-Spas/Rocky%27s-Reel-System-Inc-4751"
    #get_page(url)
    get_detail_data(get_page(url))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you also post an example of the data?

Comment: can you post the link to website or html here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to just get the tags without a class or id with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747286/is-it-possible-to-just-get-the-tags-without-a-class-or-id-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @Gauri Shankar Badola here is the link: https://secure.kelownachamber.org/Pools-Spas/Rocky%27s-Reel-System-Inc-4751

Comment: @M.Akram would be great if you could add some feedback about your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60785352/2614364)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code worked for me (this is just to show you how you can fetch data from that website so I kept it simple):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = requests.get("https://secure.kelownachamber.org/Pools-Spas/Rocky%27s-Reel-System-Inc-4751")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'html.parser')
divs  = soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"ListingDetails_Level1_HEADERBOXBOX"})
for tag in divs:
  try:
   title = tag.find("a",attrs={"class":"ListingDetails_Level1_SITELINK"}).text
   address = tag.find("span",attrs={"itemprop":"street-address"}).text
   postal = tag.find("span",attrs={"itemprop":"postal-code"}).text
   maincontact = tag.find("span",attrs={"class":"ListingDetails_Level1_MAINCONTACT"}).text
   siteTag = tag.find("span",attrs={"class":"ListingDetails_Level1_VISITSITE"})
   site = siteTag.find("a").attrs['href']
   print(title)
   print(address) 
   print(postal)
   print(maincontact)
   print(site)
  except:
   pass
```

Comment: thank you bro could you please set a loop so that program should scrape data for all listings? please  here is the link of main page: https://secure.kelownachamber.org/Automotive-Sales-Service

Comment: Done! https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-XIVST9_0fr3i5ddzjyjUBSmdQEEEUEmSqS-wcoAvN4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: hi there M.Akram hello dear Pulkit - many thanks - i run this on a MX Linux in atom and it works very well - it gives back the following: `

Rocky's Reel System Inc.
8 - 730 Stremel Road
V1X 5E7
 Jeff Hancock 1-800-663-8705  |  1-604-985-0525
http://www.rockys.ca
[Finished in 4.632s]` - many thanks for this great thread. i am currently learing python and iti s a great ressource here. - i am very very glad to have your support in the learing things.

Answer (score 2):

In cases where the elements of the page you're trying to scrape with Beautiful Soup have no classes or id's it can be hard to tell the `find()` method what you're trying to find.

In that case I prefer to use either `select()` or `select_one()` which are documented [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). These methods allow you to pass a CSS selector - the very same syntax that you use to tell your web browser which elements you want to style a particular way.

You can find a reference for what selectors are available to you [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). I cannot give you the exact CSS expression you'll need for your case because you haven't provided a sample of the HTML you're trying to scrape, but this should get you started.

For example, if the page you're trying to scrape looked like this:

```
<div id="contact">
    <div>
        <a href="ListingDetails_Level1_SITELINK">Some title</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>1, Sesame St., Address...... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then to get the address you could use a CSS selector like so:

```
address = soup.select_one("#contact > div:nth-child(2) > p")
```

The above says that the address will be found by looking in the second div immediately within the div that has the id 'contact' and then looking in the paragraph immediately within that.